# fill area in SVG

Tags: svg, colors, fill

I made a SVG out of an AutoCAD dwg file and wont to fill the area between the lines with a color.
But `fill="black"` will not work, why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   width="800.000" height="600.000" viewBox="0.0 0.0 800.000 600.000" version="1.1">
<path d="M140.6 222.19L140.61 222.66M140.61 222.66L140.63 223.13M140.63 223.13L140.67 223.61M140.67 223.61L140.71 224.09M140.71 224.09L140.78 224.56M140.78 224.56L140.86 225.04M140.86 225.04L140.95 225.52M140.95 225.52L141.05 226.01M141.05 226.01L141.18 226.49M141.18 226.49L141.31 226.97M141.31 226.97L141.46 227.46M141.46 227.46L141.63 227.95M141.63 227.95L141.81 228.43M141.81 228.43L142.01 228.92M142.01 228.92L142.22 229.41M142.22 229.41L142.45 229.9M142.45 229.9L142.69 230.39M142.69 230.39L142.95 230.88M142.95 230.88L143.22 231.38M143.22 231.38L143.51 231.87M143.51 231.87L143.82 232.36M143.82 232.36L144.14 232.86M144.14 232.86L144.48 233.35M144.48 233.35L144.83 233.85M144.83 233.85L145.2 234.35M145.2 234.35L145.59 234.84M145.59 234.84L146 235.34M146 235.34L146.42 235.84M146.42 235.84L146.85 236.34M146.85 236.34L147.31 236.83M147.31 236.83L147.78 237.33M147.78 237.33L148.26 237.83M148.26 237.83L148.77 238.33M148.77 238.33L149.29 238.83M149.29 238.83L149.83 239.33M149.83 239.33L150.38 239.82M150.38 239.82L150.96 240.32M150.96 240.32L151.55 240.82M151.55 240.82L152.15 241.32M152.15 241.32L152.78 241.82M152.78 241.82L153.42 242.32M153.42 242.32L154.08 242.81M154.08 242.81L154.75 243.31M154.75 243.31L155.44 243.81M155.44 243.81L156.15 244.3M156.15 244.3L156.88 244.8M156.88 244.8L157.63 245.29M157.63 245.29L158.39 245.79M158.39 245.79L159.17 246.28M159.17 246.28L159.97 246.77M159.97 246.77L160.78 247.26M160.78 247.26L161.62 247.75M161.62 247.75L162.47 248.24M162.47 248.24L163.34 248.73M163.34 248.73L164.22 249.22M164.22 249.22L165.12 249.71M165.12 249.71L166.04 250.19M166.04 250.19L166.98 250.68M166.98 250.68L167.94 251.16M167.94 251.16L168.91 251.64M168.91 251.64L169.9 252.12M169.9 252.12L170.9 252.6M170.9 252.6L171.93 253.08M171.93 253.08L172.97 253.55M172.97 253.55L174.03 254.03M174.03 254.03L175.1 254.5M175.1 254.5L176.19 254.97M176.19 254.97L177.3 255.44M177.3 255.44L178.43 255.91M178.43 255.91L179.57 256.37M179.57 256.37L180.73 256.83M180.73 256.83L181.91 257.29M181.91 257.29L183.1 257.75M183.1 257.75L184.31 258.21M184.31 258.21L185.54 258.66M185.54 258.66L186.78 259.12M186.78 259.12L188.04 259.57M188.04 259.57L189.31 260.01M189.31 260.01L190.6 260.46M190.6 260.46L191.91 260.9M191.91 260.9L193.23 261.34M193.23 261.34L194.57 261.78M194.57 261.78L195.92 262.22M195.92 262.22L197.29 262.65M197.29 262.65L198.68 263.08M198.68 263.08L200.08 263.5M200.08 263.5L201.49 263.93M201.49 263.93L202.92 264.35M202.92 264.35L204.36 264.77M204.36 264.77L205.82 265.18M205.82 265.18L207.3 265.6M207.3 265.6L208.78 266.01M208.78 266.01L210.29 266.41M210.29 266.41L211.8 266.81M211.8 266.81L213.33 267.21M213.33 267.21L214.87 267.61M214.87 267.61L216.43 268M216.43 268L218 268.39M218 268.39L219.59 268.78M219.59 268.78L221.18 269.16M221.18 269.16L222.79 269.54M222.79 269.54L224.41 269.92M224.41 269.92L226.05 270.29M226.05 270.29L227.7 270.66M227.7 270.66L229.35 271.03M229.35 271.03L231.03 271.39M231.03 271.39L232.71 271.75M232.71 271.75L234.4 272.1M234.4 272.1L236.11 272.45M236.11 272.45L237.82 272.8M237.82 272.8L239.55 273.14M239.55 273.14L241.29 273.48M241.29 273.48L243.04 273.81M243.04 273.81L244.8 274.15M244.8 274.15L246.57 274.47M246.57 274.47L248.35 274.8M248.35 274.8L251.93 275.43M251.93 275.43L255.56 276.05M255.56 276.05L259.22 276.65M259.22 276.65L262.91 277.24M262.91 277.24L266.63 277.81M266.63 277.81L270.39 278.36M270.39 278.36L274.17 278.89M274.17 278.89L277.98 279.41M277.98 279.41L281.81 279.91M281.81 279.91L285.67 280.4M285.67 280.4L289.55 280.86M289.55 280.86L293.44 281.31M293.44 281.31L297.35 281.74M297.35 281.74L301.28 282.15M301.28 282.15L305.23 282.55M305.23 282.55L309.18 282.93M309.18 282.93L313.14 283.29M313.14 283.29L317.12 283.63M317.12 283.63L321.1 283.96M321.1 283.96L325.08 284.27M325.08 284.27L329.07 284.56M329.07 284.56L333.06 284.84M333.06 284.84L337.05 285.1M337.05 285.1L341.03 285.34M341.03 285.34L345.02 285.56M345.02 285.56L349 285.77M349 285.77L352.97 285.96M352.97 285.96L356.93 286.13M356.93 286.13L360.89 286.29M360.89 286.29L364.83 286.44M364.83 286.44L368.77 286.56M368.77 286.56L372.69 286.67M372.69 286.67L376.59 286.77M376.59 286.77L380.48 286.85M380.48 286.85L384.35 286.92M384.35 286.92L388.21 286.97M388.21 286.97L392.04 287M392.04 287L395.85 287.03M395.85 287.03L399.64 287.03M399.64 287.03L403.43 287.03M403.43 287.03L407.24 287.01M407.24 287.01L411.07 286.98M411.07 286.98L414.92 286.93M414.92 286.93L418.79 286.86M418.79 286.86L422.68 286.79M422.68 286.79L426.58 286.69M426.58 286.69L430.49 286.58M430.49 286.58L434.42 286.46M434.42 286.46L438.37 286.32M438.37 286.32L442.32 286.17M442.32 286.17L446.28 285.99M446.28 285.99L450.26 285.81M450.26 285.81L454.23 285.6M454.23 285.6L458.22 285.38M458.22 285.38L462.2 285.14M462.2 285.14L466.19 284.89M466.19 284.89L470.18 284.62M470.18 284.62L474.17 284.33M474.17 284.33L478.15 284.02M478.15 284.02L482.14 283.7M482.14 283.7L486.11 283.36M486.11 283.36L490.08 283M490.08 283L494.03 282.62M494.03 282.62L497.98 282.23M497.98 282.23L501.91 281.82M501.91 281.82L505.82 281.39M505.82 281.39L509.72 280.95M509.72 280.95L513.6 280.48M513.6 280.48L517.46 280M517.46 280L521.3 279.51M521.3 279.51L525.12 278.99M525.12 278.99L528.9 278.46M528.9 278.46L532.66 277.91M532.66 277.91L536.39 277.35M536.39 277.35L540.09 276.76M540.09 276.76L543.76 276.16M543.76 276.16L547.39 275.55M547.39 275.55L550.98 274.92M550.98 274.92L552.77 274.6M552.77 274.6L554.54 274.27M554.54 274.27L556.3 273.94M556.3 273.94L558.05 273.61M558.05 273.61L559.8 273.27M559.8 273.27L561.53 272.93M561.53 272.93L563.25 272.58M563.25 272.58L564.96 272.23M564.96 272.23L566.66 271.88M566.66 271.88L568.34 271.52M568.34 271.52L570.02 271.16M570.02 271.16L571.68 270.8M571.68 270.8L573.33 270.43M573.33 270.43L574.97 270.06M574.97 270.06L576.6 269.68M576.6 269.68L578.21 269.31M578.21 269.31L579.82 268.92M579.82 268.92L581.4 268.54M581.4 268.54L582.98 268.15M582.98 268.15L584.54 267.76M584.54 267.76L586.09 267.36M586.09 267.36L587.62 266.96M587.62 266.96L589.15 266.56M589.15 266.56L590.65 266.16M590.65 266.16L592.15 265.75M592.15 265.75L593.63 265.34M593.63 265.34L595.09 264.92M595.09 264.92L596.54 264.51M596.54 264.51L597.97 264.09M597.97 264.09L599.39 263.66M599.39 263.66L600.8 263.24M600.8 263.24L602.19 262.81M602.19 262.81L603.56 262.38M603.56 262.38L604.92 261.94M604.92 261.94L606.27 261.51M606.27 261.51L607.6 261.07M607.6 261.07L608.91 260.63M608.91 260.63L610.2 260.18M610.2 260.18L611.49 259.74M611.49 259.74L612.75 259.29M612.75 259.29L614 258.84M614 258.84L615.23 258.38M615.23 258.38L616.45 257.93M616.45 257.93L617.64 257.47M617.64 257.47L618.83 257.01M618.83 257.01L619.99 256.54M619.99 256.54L621.14 256.08M621.14 256.08L622.28 255.61M622.28 255.61L623.39 255.15M623.39 255.15L624.49 254.68M624.49 254.68L625.57 254.2M625.57 254.2L626.64 253.73M626.64 253.73L627.68 253.26M627.68 253.26L628.71 252.78M628.71 252.78L629.73 252.3M629.73 252.3L630.72 251.82M630.72 251.82L631.7 251.34M631.7 251.34L632.66 250.86M632.66 250.86L633.61 250.37M633.61 250.37L634.53 249.89M634.53 249.89L635.44 249.4M635.44 249.4L636.33 248.92M636.33 248.92L637.21 248.43M637.21 248.43L638.06 247.94M638.06 247.94L638.9 247.45M638.9 247.45L639.73 246.96M639.73 246.96L640.53 246.46M640.53 246.46L641.32 245.97M641.32 245.97L642.09 245.48M642.09 245.48L642.84 244.98M642.84 244.98L643.57 244.49M643.57 244.49L644.29 243.99M644.29 243.99L644.99 243.5M644.99 243.5L645.67 243M645.67 243L646.34 242.5M646.34 242.5L646.99 242M646.99 242L647.62 241.51M647.62 241.51L648.23 241.01M648.23 241.01L648.82 240.51M648.82 240.51L649.4 240.01M649.4 240.01L649.96 239.51M649.96 239.51L650.51 239.01M650.51 239.01L651.04 238.52M651.04 238.52L651.55 238.02M651.55 238.02L652.04 237.52M652.04 237.52L652.52 237.02M652.52 237.02L652.98 236.52M652.98 236.52L653.42 236.02M653.42 236.02L653.85 235.53M653.85 235.53L654.26 235.03M654.26 235.03L654.65 234.53M654.65 234.53L655.03 234.04M655.03 234.04L655.39 233.54M655.39 233.54L655.73 233.04M655.73 233.04L656.06 232.55M656.06 232.55L656.37 232.06M656.37 232.06L656.67 231.56M656.67 231.56L656.95 231.07M656.95 231.07L657.22 230.58M657.22 230.58L657.46 230.09M657.46 230.09L657.7 229.59M657.7 229.59L657.92 229.11M657.92 229.11L658.12 228.62M658.12 228.62L658.31 228.13M658.31 228.13L658.48 227.64M658.48 227.64L658.63 227.16M658.63 227.16L658.78 226.67M658.78 226.67L658.9 226.19M658.9 226.19L659.01 225.71M659.01 225.71L659.11 225.22M659.11 225.22L659.19 224.74M659.19 224.74L659.26 224.26M659.26 224.26L659.32 223.79M659.32 223.79L659.36 223.31M659.36 223.31L659.38 222.84M659.38 222.84L659.4 222.36M659.4 222.36L659.4 222.24M659.4 222.24L659.4 222.19M659.4 222.19L659.4 222.06M659.4 222.06L659.4 221.53M659.4 221.53L659.4 220.48M659.4 220.48L659.4 218.38M659.4 218.38L659.4 209.99M659.4 209.99L659.4 193.2M659.4 193.2L659.4 159.63M659.4 159.63L659.4 92.49M659.4 92.49L659.39 92.96M659.39 92.96L659.37 93.43M659.37 93.43L659.33 93.91M659.33 93.91L659.29 94.39M659.29 94.39L659.22 94.87M659.22 94.87L659.14 95.34M659.14 95.34L659.05 95.83M659.05 95.83L658.95 96.31M658.95 96.31L658.82 96.79M658.82 96.79L658.69 97.28M658.69 97.28L658.54 97.76M658.54 97.76L658.37 98.25M658.37 98.25L658.19 98.73M658.19 98.73L657.99 99.22M657.99 99.22L657.78 99.71M657.78 99.71L657.55 100.2M657.55 100.2L657.31 100.69M657.31 100.69L657.05 101.19M657.05 101.19L656.78 101.68M656.78 101.68L656.49 102.17M656.49 102.17L656.18 102.67M656.18 102.67L655.86 103.16M655.86 103.16L655.52 103.66M655.52 103.66L655.17 104.15M655.17 104.15L654.8 104.65M654.8 104.65L654.41 105.14M654.41 105.14L654 105.64M654 105.64L653.58 106.14M653.58 106.14L653.15 106.64M653.15 106.64L652.69 107.13M652.69 107.13L652.22 107.63M652.22 107.63L651.74 108.13M651.74 108.13L651.23 108.63M651.23 108.63L650.71 109.13M650.71 109.13L650.17 109.63M650.17 109.63L649.62 110.13M649.62 110.13L649.04 110.62M649.04 110.62L648.45 111.12M648.45 111.12L647.85 111.62M647.85 111.62L647.22 112.12M647.22 112.12L646.58 112.62M646.58 112.62L645.92 113.11M645.92 113.11L645.25 113.61M645.25 113.61L644.56 114.11M644.56 114.11L643.85 114.6M643.85 114.6L643.12 115.1M643.12 115.1L642.37 115.59M642.37 115.59L641.61 116.09M641.61 116.09L640.83 116.58M640.83 116.58L640.03 117.07M640.03 117.07L639.22 117.56M639.22 117.56L638.38 118.06M638.38 118.06L637.53 118.55M637.53 118.55L636.66 119.03M636.66 119.03L635.78 119.52M635.78 119.52L634.88 120.01M634.88 120.01L633.96 120.49M633.96 120.49L633.02 120.98M633.02 120.98L632.06 121.46M632.06 121.46L631.09 121.94M631.09 121.94L630.1 122.42M630.1 122.42L629.1 122.9M629.1 122.9L628.07 123.38M628.07 123.38L627.03 123.85M627.03 123.85L625.97 124.33M625.97 124.33L624.9 124.8M624.9 124.8L623.81 125.27M623.81 125.27L622.7 125.74M622.7 125.74L621.57 126.21M621.57 126.21L620.43 126.67M620.43 126.67L619.27 127.14M619.27 127.14L618.09 127.6M618.09 127.6L616.9 128.05M616.9 128.05L615.69 128.51M615.69 128.51L614.46 128.97M614.46 128.97L613.22 129.42M613.22 129.42L611.96 129.87M611.96 129.87L610.69 130.32M610.69 130.32L609.4 130.76M609.4 130.76L608.09 131.2M608.09 131.2L606.77 131.64M606.77 131.64L605.43 132.08M605.43 132.08L604.08 132.52M604.08 132.52L602.71 132.95M602.71 132.95L601.32 133.38M601.32 133.38L599.92 133.81M599.92 133.81L598.51 134.23M598.51 134.23L597.08 134.65M597.08 134.65L595.64 135.07M595.64 135.07L594.18 135.49M594.18 135.49L592.7 135.9M592.7 135.9L591.22 136.31M591.22 136.31L589.71 136.71M589.71 136.71L588.2 137.12M588.2 137.12L586.67 137.52M586.67 137.52L585.13 137.91M585.13 137.91L583.57 138.31M583.57 138.31L582 138.7M582 138.7L580.41 139.08M580.41 139.08L578.82 139.46M578.82 139.46L577.21 139.84M577.21 139.84L575.59 140.22M575.59 140.22L573.95 140.59M573.95 140.59L572.3 140.96M572.3 140.96L570.65 141.33M570.65 141.33L568.97 141.69M568.97 141.69L567.29 142.05M567.29 142.05L565.6 142.4M565.6 142.4L563.89 142.75M563.89 142.75L562.18 143.1M562.18 143.1L560.45 143.44M560.45 143.44L558.71 143.78M558.71 143.78L556.96 144.12M556.96 144.12L555.2 144.45M555.2 144.45L553.43 144.77M553.43 144.77L551.65 145.1M551.65 145.1L548.07 145.73M548.07 145.73L544.44 146.35M544.44 146.35L540.78 146.95M540.78 146.95L537.09 147.54M537.09 147.54L533.37 148.11M533.37 148.11L529.61 148.66M529.61 148.66L525.83 149.2M525.83 149.2L522.02 149.71M522.02 149.71L518.19 150.21M518.19 150.21L514.33 150.7M514.33 150.7L510.45 151.16M510.45 151.16L506.56 151.61M506.56 151.61L502.65 152.04M502.65 152.04L498.72 152.46M498.72 152.46L494.77 152.85M494.77 152.85L490.82 153.23M490.82 153.23L486.86 153.59M486.86 153.59L482.88 153.94M482.88 153.94L478.9 154.26M478.9 154.26L474.92 154.57M474.92 154.57L470.93 154.86M470.93 154.86L466.94 155.14M466.94 155.14L462.95 155.4M462.95 155.4L458.97 155.64M458.97 155.64L454.98 155.86M454.98 155.86L451 156.07M451 156.07L447.03 156.26M447.03 156.26L443.07 156.44M443.07 156.44L439.11 156.59M439.11 156.59L435.17 156.74M435.17 156.74L431.23 156.86M431.23 156.86L427.31 156.98M427.31 156.98L423.41 157.07M423.41 157.07L419.52 157.15M419.52 157.15L415.65 157.22M415.65 157.22L411.79 157.27M411.79 157.27L407.96 157.31M407.96 157.31L404.15 157.33M404.15 157.33L400.36 157.34M400.36 157.34L396.57 157.33M396.57 157.33L392.76 157.31M392.76 157.31L388.93 157.28M388.93 157.28L385.08 157.23M385.08 157.23L381.21 157.17M381.21 157.17L377.32 157.09M377.32 157.09L373.42 156.99M373.42 156.99L369.51 156.89M369.51 156.89L365.58 156.76M365.58 156.76L361.63 156.62M361.63 156.62L357.68 156.47M357.68 156.47L353.72 156.3M353.72 156.3L349.74 156.11M349.74 156.11L345.77 155.9M345.77 155.9L341.78 155.68M341.78 155.68L337.8 155.44M337.8 155.44L333.81 155.19M333.81 155.19L329.82 154.92M329.82 154.92L325.83 154.63M325.83 154.63L321.85 154.32M321.85 154.32L317.86 154M317.86 154L313.89 153.66M313.89 153.66L309.92 153.3M309.92 153.3L305.97 152.93M305.97 152.93L302.02 152.53M302.02 152.53L298.09 152.12M298.09 152.12L294.18 151.69M294.18 151.69L290.28 151.25M290.28 151.25L286.4 150.79M286.4 150.79L282.54 150.31M282.54 150.31L278.7 149.81M278.7 149.81L274.88 149.29M274.88 149.29L271.1 148.76M271.1 148.76L267.34 148.21M267.34 148.21L263.61 147.65M263.61 147.65L259.91 147.07M259.91 147.07L256.24 146.47M256.24 146.47L252.61 145.85M252.61 145.85L249.02 145.22M249.02 145.22L247.23 144.9M247.23 144.9L245.46 144.57M245.46 144.57L243.7 144.24M243.7 144.24L241.95 143.91M241.95 143.91L240.2 143.57M240.2 143.57L238.47 143.23M238.47 143.23L236.75 142.88M236.75 142.88L235.04 142.53M235.04 142.53L233.34 142.18M233.34 142.18L231.66 141.82M231.66 141.82L229.98 141.46M229.98 141.46L228.32 141.1M228.32 141.1L226.67 140.73M226.67 140.73L225.03 140.36M225.03 140.36L223.4 139.99M223.4 139.99L221.79 139.61M221.79 139.61L220.18 139.23M220.18 139.23L218.6 138.84M218.6 138.84L217.02 138.45M217.02 138.45L215.46 138.06M215.46 138.06L213.91 137.66M213.91 137.66L212.38 137.27M212.38 137.27L210.85 136.86M210.85 136.86L209.35 136.46M209.35 136.46L207.85 136.05M207.85 136.05L206.37 135.64M206.37 135.64L204.91 135.23M204.91 135.23L203.46 134.81M203.46 134.81L202.03 134.39M202.03 134.39L200.61 133.97M200.61 133.97L199.2 133.54M199.2 133.54L197.81 133.11M197.81 133.11L196.44 132.68M196.44 132.68L195.08 132.25M195.08 132.25L193.73 131.81M193.73 131.81L192.4 131.37M192.4 131.37L191.09 130.93M191.09 130.93L189.8 130.48M189.8 130.48L188.51 130.04M188.51 130.04L187.25 129.59M187.25 129.59L186 129.14M186 129.14L184.77 128.68M184.77 128.68L183.55 128.23M183.55 128.23L182.36 127.77M182.36 127.77L181.17 127.31M181.17 127.31L180.01 126.85M180.01 126.85L178.86 126.38M178.86 126.38L177.72 125.92M177.72 125.92L176.61 125.45M176.61 125.45L175.51 124.98M175.51 124.98L174.43 124.51M174.43 124.51L173.36 124.03M173.36 124.03L172.32 123.56M172.32 123.56L171.29 123.08M171.29 123.08L170.27 122.6M170.27 122.6L169.28 122.12M169.28 122.12L168.3 121.64M168.3 121.64L167.34 121.16M167.34 121.16L166.39 120.68M166.39 120.68L165.47 120.19M165.47 120.19L164.56 119.71M164.56 119.71L163.67 119.22M163.67 119.22L162.79 118.73M162.79 118.73L161.94 118.24M161.94 118.24L161.1 117.75M161.1 117.75L160.27 117.26M160.27 117.26L159.47 116.77M159.47 116.77L158.68 116.27M158.68 116.27L157.91 115.78M157.91 115.78L157.16 115.28M157.16 115.28L156.43 114.79M156.43 114.79L155.71 114.29M155.71 114.29L155.01 113.8M155.01 113.8L154.33 113.3M154.33 113.3L153.66 112.8M153.66 112.8L153.01 112.31M153.01 112.31L152.38 111.81M152.38 111.81L151.77 111.31M151.77 111.31L151.18 110.81M151.18 110.81L150.6 110.31M150.6 110.31L150.04 109.81M150.04 109.81L149.49 109.32M149.49 109.32L148.96 108.82M148.96 108.82L148.45 108.32M148.45 108.32L147.96 107.82M147.96 107.82L147.48 107.32M147.48 107.32L147.02 106.82M147.02 106.82L146.58 106.33M146.58 106.33L146.15 105.83M146.15 105.83L145.74 105.33M145.74 105.33L145.35 104.83M145.35 104.83L144.97 104.34M144.97 104.34L144.61 103.84M144.61 103.84L144.27 103.35M144.27 103.35L143.94 102.85M143.94 102.85L143.63 102.36M143.63 102.36L143.33 101.86M143.33 101.86L143.05 101.37M143.05 101.37L142.78 100.88M142.78 100.88L142.54 100.39M142.54 100.39L142.3 99.9M142.3 99.9L142.08 99.41M142.08 99.41L141.88 98.92M141.88 98.92L141.69 98.43M141.69 98.43L141.52 97.94M141.52 97.94L141.37 97.46M141.37 97.46L141.22 96.97M141.22 96.97L141.1 96.49M141.1 96.49L140.99 96.01M140.99 96.01L140.89 95.53M140.89 95.53L140.81 95.05M140.81 95.05L140.74 94.57M140.74 94.57L140.68 94.09M140.68 94.09L140.64 93.61M140.64 93.61L140.62 93.14M140.62 93.14L140.6 92.66M140.6 92.66L140.6 92.55M140.6 92.55L140.6 92.49M140.6 92.49L140.6 92.62M140.6 92.62L140.6 93.14M140.6 93.14L140.6 94.19M140.6 94.19L140.6 96.29M140.6 96.29L140.6 104.68M140.6 104.68L140.6 121.47M140.6 121.47L140.6 155.04M140.6 155.04L140.6 222.19"
fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2.5"/>
</svg>
```

This codde snippet is just a part of teh file.

Comment: Can you try optimizing the path? Use actual curves or something

Comment: What do you mean with "optimize"? The path is the result of the converter. edit: ah okay, my svg is not a vector but a "a-lot-of-dots" graphic.

Comment: Well your converter cut up curves into many time lines that define an outline instead. I'll try and see if I can redraw the shape with less stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing what is requested. You are drawing a filled outline.

You need to either file a bug report, or edit the file yourself by replacing all the `M` & `L` from the `PATH` statement with the exception of the first `M` as in (I changed the `fill` to `red` to highlight):

```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   width="800.000" height="600.000" viewBox="0.0 0.0 800.000 600.000" version="1.1">
    <path d="M140.6 222.19 140.61 222.66 140.61 222.66 140.63 223.13 140.63 223.13 140.67 223.61 140.67 223.61 140.71 224.09 140.71 224.09 140.78 224.56 140.78 224.56 140.86 225.04 140.86 225.04 140.95 225.52 140.95 225.52 141.05 226.01 141.05 226.01 141.18 226.49 141.18 226.49 141.31 226.97 141.31 226.97 141.46 227.46 141.46 227.46 141.63 227.95 141.63 227.95 141.81 228.43 141.81 228.43 142.01 228.92 142.01 228.92 142.22 229.41 142.22 229.41 142.45 229.9 142.45 229.9 142.69 230.39 142.69 230.39 142.95 230.88 142.95 230.88 143.22 231.38 143.22 231.38 143.51 231.87 143.51 231.87 143.82 232.36 143.82 232.36 144.14 232.86 144.14 232.86 144.48 233.35 144.48 233.35 144.83 233.85 144.83 233.85 145.2 234.35 145.2 234.35 145.59 234.84 145.59 234.84 146 235.34 146 235.34 146.42 235.84 146.42 235.84 146.85 236.34 146.85 236.34 147.31 236.83 147.31 236.83 147.78 237.33 147.78 237.33 148.26 237.83 148.26 237.83 148.77 238.33 148.77 238.33 149.29 238.83 149.29 238.83 149.83 239.33 149.83 239.33 150.38 239.82 150.38 239.82 150.96 240.32 150.96 240.32 151.55 240.82 151.55 240.82 152.15 241.32 152.15 241.32 152.78 241.82 152.78 241.82 153.42 242.32 153.42 242.32 154.08 242.81 154.08 242.81 154.75 243.31 154.75 243.31 155.44 243.81 155.44 243.81 156.15 244.3 156.15 244.3 156.88 244.8 156.88 244.8 157.63 245.29 157.63 245.29 158.39 245.79 158.39 245.79 159.17 246.28 159.17 246.28 159.97 246.77 159.97 246.77 160.78 247.26 160.78 247.26 161.62 247.75 161.62 247.75 162.47 248.24 162.47 248.24 163.34 248.73 163.34 248.73 164.22 249.22 164.22 249.22 165.12 249.71 165.12 249.71 166.04 250.19 166.04 250.19 166.98 250.68 166.98 250.68 167.94 251.16 167.94 251.16 168.91 251.64 168.91 251.64 169.9 252.12 169.9 252.12 170.9 252.6 170.9 252.6 171.93 253.08 171.93 253.08 172.97 253.55 172.97 253.55 174.03 254.03 174.03 254.03 175.1 254.5 175.1 254.5 176.19 254.97 176.19 254.97 177.3 255.44 177.3 255.44 178.43 255.91 178.43 255.91 179.57 256.37 179.57 256.37 180.73 256.83 180.73 256.83 181.91 257.29 181.91 257.29 183.1 257.75 183.1 257.75 184.31 258.21 184.31 258.21 185.54 258.66 185.54 258.66 186.78 259.12 186.78 259.12 188.04 259.57 188.04 259.57 189.31 260.01 189.31 260.01 190.6 260.46 190.6 260.46 191.91 260.9 191.91 260.9 193.23 261.34 193.23 261.34 194.57 261.78 194.57 261.78 195.92 262.22 195.92 262.22 197.29 262.65 197.29 262.65 198.68 263.08 198.68 263.08 200.08 263.5 200.08 263.5 201.49 263.93 201.49 263.93 202.92 264.35 202.92 264.35 204.36 264.77 204.36 264.77 205.82 265.18 205.82 265.18 207.3 265.6 207.3 265.6 208.78 266.01 208.78 266.01 210.29 266.41 210.29 266.41 211.8 266.81 211.8 266.81 213.33 267.21 213.33 267.21 214.87 267.61 214.87 267.61 216.43 268 216.43 268 218 268.39 218 268.39 219.59 268.78 219.59 268.78 221.18 269.16 221.18 269.16 222.79 269.54 222.79 269.54 224.41 269.92 224.41 269.92 226.05 270.29 226.05 270.29 227.7 270.66 227.7 270.66 229.35 271.03 229.35 271.03 231.03 271.39 231.03 271.39 232.71 271.75 232.71 271.75 234.4 272.1 234.4 272.1 236.11 272.45 236.11 272.45 237.82 272.8 237.82 272.8 239.55 273.14 239.55 273.14 241.29 273.48 241.29 273.48 243.04 273.81 243.04 273.81 244.8 274.15 244.8 274.15 246.57 274.47 246.57 274.47 248.35 274.8 248.35 274.8 251.93 275.43 251.93 275.43 255.56 276.05 255.56 276.05 259.22 276.65 259.22 276.65 262.91 277.24 262.91 277.24 266.63 277.81 266.63 277.81 270.39 278.36 270.39 278.36 274.17 278.89 274.17 278.89 277.98 279.41 277.98 279.41 281.81 279.91 281.81 279.91 285.67 280.4 285.67 280.4 289.55 280.86 289.55 280.86 293.44 281.31 293.44 281.31 297.35 281.74 297.35 281.74 301.28 282.15 301.28 282.15 305.23 282.55 305.23 282.55 309.18 282.93 309.18 282.93 313.14 283.29 313.14 283.29 317.12 283.63 317.12 283.63 321.1 283.96 321.1 283.96 325.08 284.27 325.08 284.27 329.07 284.56 329.07 284.56 333.06 284.84 333.06 284.84 337.05 285.1 337.05 285.1 341.03 285.34 341.03 285.34 345.02 285.56 345.02 285.56 349 285.77 349 285.77 352.97 285.96 352.97 285.96 356.93 286.13 356.93 286.13 360.89 286.29 360.89 286.29 364.83 286.44 364.83 286.44 368.77 286.56 368.77 286.56 372.69 286.67 372.69 286.67 376.59 286.77 376.59 286.77 380.48 286.85 380.48 286.85 384.35 286.92 384.35 286.92 388.21 286.97 388.21 286.97 392.04 287 392.04 287 395.85 287.03 395.85 287.03 399.64 287.03 399.64 287.03 403.43 287.03 403.43 287.03 407.24 287.01 407.24 287.01 411.07 286.98 411.07 286.98 414.92 286.93 414.92 286.93 418.79 286.86 418.79 286.86 422.68 286.79 422.68 286.79 426.58 286.69 426.58 286.69 430.49 286.58 430.49 286.58 434.42 286.46 434.42 286.46 438.37 286.32 438.37 286.32 442.32 286.17 442.32 286.17 446.28 285.99 446.28 285.99 450.26 285.81 450.26 285.81 454.23 285.6 454.23 285.6 458.22 285.38 458.22 285.38 462.2 285.14 462.2 285.14 466.19 284.89 466.19 284.89 470.18 284.62 470.18 284.62 474.17 284.33 474.17 284.33 478.15 284.02 478.15 284.02 482.14 283.7 482.14 283.7 486.11 283.36 486.11 283.36 490.08 283 490.08 283 494.03 282.62 494.03 282.62 497.98 282.23 497.98 282.23 501.91 281.82 501.91 281.82 505.82 281.39 505.82 281.39 509.72 280.95 509.72 280.95 513.6 280.48 513.6 280.48 517.46 280 517.46 280 521.3 279.51 521.3 279.51 525.12 278.99 525.12 278.99 528.9 278.46 528.9 278.46 532.66 277.91 532.66 277.91 536.39 277.35 536.39 277.35 540.09 276.76 540.09 276.76 543.76 276.16 543.76 276.16 547.39 275.55 547.39 275.55 550.98 274.92 550.98 274.92 552.77 274.6 552.77 274.6 554.54 274.27 554.54 274.27 556.3 273.94 556.3 273.94 558.05 273.61 558.05 273.61 559.8 273.27 559.8 273.27 561.53 272.93 561.53 272.93 563.25 272.58 563.25 272.58 564.96 272.23 564.96 272.23 566.66 271.88 566.66 271.88 568.34 271.52 568.34 271.52 570.02 271.16 570.02 271.16 571.68 270.8 571.68 270.8 573.33 270.43 573.33 270.43 574.97 270.06 574.97 270.06 576.6 269.68 576.6 269.68 578.21 269.31 578.21 269.31 579.82 268.92 579.82 268.92 581.4 268.54 581.4 268.54 582.98 268.15 582.98 268.15 584.54 267.76 584.54 267.76 586.09 267.36 586.09 267.36 587.62 266.96 587.62 266.96 589.15 266.56 589.15 266.56 590.65 266.16 590.65 266.16 592.15 265.75 592.15 265.75 593.63 265.34 593.63 265.34 595.09 264.92 595.09 264.92 596.54 264.51 596.54 264.51 597.97 264.09 597.97 264.09 599.39 263.66 599.39 263.66 600.8 263.24 600.8 263.24 602.19 262.81 602.19 262.81 603.56 262.38 603.56 262.38 604.92 261.94 604.92 261.94 606.27 261.51 606.27 261.51 607.6 261.07 607.6 261.07 608.91 260.63 608.91 260.63 610.2 260.18 610.2 260.18 611.49 259.74 611.49 259.74 612.75 259.29 612.75 259.29 614 258.84 614 258.84 615.23 258.38 615.23 258.38 616.45 257.93 616.45 257.93 617.64 257.47 617.64 257.47 618.83 257.01 618.83 257.01 619.99 256.54 619.99 256.54 621.14 256.08 621.14 256.08 622.28 255.61 622.28 255.61 623.39 255.15 623.39 255.15 624.49 254.68 624.49 254.68 625.57 254.2 625.57 254.2 626.64 253.73 626.64 253.73 627.68 253.26 627.68 253.26 628.71 252.78 628.71 252.78 629.73 252.3 629.73 252.3 630.72 251.82 630.72 251.82 631.7 251.34 631.7 251.34 632.66 250.86 632.66 250.86 633.61 250.37 633.61 250.37 634.53 249.89 634.53 249.89 635.44 249.4 635.44 249.4 636.33 248.92 636.33 248.92 637.21 248.43 637.21 248.43 638.06 247.94 638.06 247.94 638.9 247.45 638.9 247.45 639.73 246.96 639.73 246.96 640.53 246.46 640.53 246.46 641.32 245.97 641.32 245.97 642.09 245.48 642.09 245.48 642.84 244.98 642.84 244.98 643.57 244.49 643.57 244.49 644.29 243.99 644.29 243.99 644.99 243.5 644.99 243.5 645.67 243 645.67 243 646.34 242.5 646.34 242.5 646.99 242 646.99 242 647.62 241.51 647.62 241.51 648.23 241.01 648.23 241.01 648.82 240.51 648.82 240.51 649.4 240.01 649.4 240.01 649.96 239.51 649.96 239.51 650.51 239.01 650.51 239.01 651.04 238.52 651.04 238.52 651.55 238.02 651.55 238.02 652.04 237.52 652.04 237.52 652.52 237.02 652.52 237.02 652.98 236.52 652.98 236.52 653.42 236.02 653.42 236.02 653.85 235.53 653.85 235.53 654.26 235.03 654.26 235.03 654.65 234.53 654.65 234.53 655.03 234.04 655.03 234.04 655.39 233.54 655.39 233.54 655.73 233.04 655.73 233.04 656.06 232.55 656.06 232.55 656.37 232.06 656.37 232.06 656.67 231.56 656.67 231.56 656.95 231.07 656.95 231.07 657.22 230.58 657.22 230.58 657.46 230.09 657.46 230.09 657.7 229.59 657.7 229.59 657.92 229.11 657.92 229.11 658.12 228.62 658.12 228.62 658.31 228.13 658.31 228.13 658.48 227.64 658.48 227.64 658.63 227.16 658.63 227.16 658.78 226.67 658.78 226.67 658.9 226.19 658.9 226.19 659.01 225.71 659.01 225.71 659.11 225.22 659.11 225.22 659.19 224.74 659.19 224.74 659.26 224.26 659.26 224.26 659.32 223.79 659.32 223.79 659.36 223.31 659.36 223.31 659.38 222.84 659.38 222.84 659.4 222.36 659.4 222.36 659.4 222.24 659.4 222.24 659.4 222.19 659.4 222.19 659.4 222.06 659.4 222.06 659.4 221.53 659.4 221.53 659.4 220.48 659.4 220.48 659.4 218.38 659.4 218.38 659.4 209.99 659.4 209.99 659.4 193.2 659.4 193.2 659.4 159.63 659.4 159.63 659.4 92.49 659.4 92.49 659.39 92.96 659.39 92.96 659.37 93.43 659.37 93.43 659.33 93.91 659.33 93.91 659.29 94.39 659.29 94.39 659.22 94.87 659.22 94.87 659.14 95.34 659.14 95.34 659.05 95.83 659.05 95.83 658.95 96.31 658.95 96.31 658.82 96.79 658.82 96.79 658.69 97.28 658.69 97.28 658.54 97.76 658.54 97.76 658.37 98.25 658.37 98.25 658.19 98.73 658.19 98.73 657.99 99.22 657.99 99.22 657.78 99.71 657.78 99.71 657.55 100.2 657.55 100.2 657.31 100.69 657.31 100.69 657.05 101.19 657.05 101.19 656.78 101.68 656.78 101.68 656.49 102.17 656.49 102.17 656.18 102.67 656.18 102.67 655.86 103.16 655.86 103.16 655.52 103.66 655.52 103.66 655.17 104.15 655.17 104.15 654.8 104.65 654.8 104.65 654.41 105.14 654.41 105.14 654 105.64 654 105.64 653.58 106.14 653.58 106.14 653.15 106.64 653.15 106.64 652.69 107.13 652.69 107.13 652.22 107.63 652.22 107.63 651.74 108.13 651.74 108.13 651.23 108.63 651.23 108.63 650.71 109.13 650.71 109.13 650.17 109.63 650.17 109.63 649.62 110.13 649.62 110.13 649.04 110.62 649.04 110.62 648.45 111.12 648.45 111.12 647.85 111.62 647.85 111.62 647.22 112.12 647.22 112.12 646.58 112.62 646.58 112.62 645.92 113.11 645.92 113.11 645.25 113.61 645.25 113.61 644.56 114.11 644.56 114.11 643.85 114.6 643.85 114.6 643.12 115.1 643.12 115.1 642.37 115.59 642.37 115.59 641.61 116.09 641.61 116.09 640.83 116.58 640.83 116.58 640.03 117.07 640.03 117.07 639.22 117.56 639.22 117.56 638.38 118.06 638.38 118.06 637.53 118.55 637.53 118.55 636.66 119.03 636.66 119.03 635.78 119.52 635.78 119.52 634.88 120.01 634.88 120.01 633.96 120.49 633.96 120.49 633.02 120.98 633.02 120.98 632.06 121.46 632.06 121.46 631.09 121.94 631.09 121.94 630.1 122.42 630.1 122.42 629.1 122.9 629.1 122.9 628.07 123.38 628.07 123.38 627.03 123.85 627.03 123.85 625.97 124.33 625.97 124.33 624.9 124.8 624.9 124.8 623.81 125.27 623.81 125.27 622.7 125.74 622.7 125.74 621.57 126.21 621.57 126.21 620.43 126.67 620.43 126.67 619.27 127.14 619.27 127.14 618.09 127.6 618.09 127.6 616.9 128.05 616.9 128.05 615.69 128.51 615.69 128.51 614.46 128.97 614.46 128.97 613.22 129.42 613.22 129.42 611.96 129.87 611.96 129.87 610.69 130.32 610.69 130.32 609.4 130.76 609.4 130.76 608.09 131.2 608.09 131.2 606.77 131.64 606.77 131.64 605.43 132.08 605.43 132.08 604.08 132.52 604.08 132.52 602.71 132.95 602.71 132.95 601.32 133.38 601.32 133.38 599.92 133.81 599.92 133.81 598.51 134.23 598.51 134.23 597.08 134.65 597.08 134.65 595.64 135.07 595.64 135.07 594.18 135.49 594.18 135.49 592.7 135.9 592.7 135.9 591.22 136.31 591.22 136.31 589.71 136.71 589.71 136.71 588.2 137.12 588.2 137.12 586.67 137.52 586.67 137.52 585.13 137.91 585.13 137.91 583.57 138.31 583.57 138.31 582 138.7 582 138.7 580.41 139.08 580.41 139.08 578.82 139.46 578.82 139.46 577.21 139.84 577.21 139.84 575.59 140.22 575.59 140.22 573.95 140.59 573.95 140.59 572.3 140.96 572.3 140.96 570.65 141.33 570.65 141.33 568.97 141.69 568.97 141.69 567.29 142.05 567.29 142.05 565.6 142.4 565.6 142.4 563.89 142.75 563.89 142.75 562.18 143.1 562.18 143.1 560.45 143.44 560.45 143.44 558.71 143.78 558.71 143.78 556.96 144.12 556.96 144.12 555.2 144.45 555.2 144.45 553.43 144.77 553.43 144.77 551.65 145.1 551.65 145.1 548.07 145.73 548.07 145.73 544.44 146.35 544.44 146.35 540.78 146.95 540.78 146.95 537.09 147.54 537.09 147.54 533.37 148.11 533.37 148.11 529.61 148.66 529.61 148.66 525.83 149.2 525.83 149.2 522.02 149.71 522.02 149.71 518.19 150.21 518.19 150.21 514.33 150.7 514.33 150.7 510.45 151.16 510.45 151.16 506.56 151.61 506.56 151.61 502.65 152.04 502.65 152.04 498.72 152.46 498.72 152.46 494.77 152.85 494.77 152.85 490.82 153.23 490.82 153.23 486.86 153.59 486.86 153.59 482.88 153.94 482.88 153.94 478.9 154.26 478.9 154.26 474.92 154.57 474.92 154.57 470.93 154.86 470.93 154.86 466.94 155.14 466.94 155.14 462.95 155.4 462.95 155.4 458.97 155.64 458.97 155.64 454.98 155.86 454.98 155.86 451 156.07 451 156.07 447.03 156.26 447.03 156.26 443.07 156.44 443.07 156.44 439.11 156.59 439.11 156.59 435.17 156.74 435.17 156.74 431.23 156.86 431.23 156.86 427.31 156.98 427.31 156.98 423.41 157.07 423.41 157.07 419.52 157.15 419.52 157.15 415.65 157.22 415.65 157.22 411.79 157.27 411.79 157.27 407.96 157.31 407.96 157.31 404.15 157.33 404.15 157.33 400.36 157.34 400.36 157.34 396.57 157.33 396.57 157.33 392.76 157.31 392.76 157.31 388.93 157.28 388.93 157.28 385.08 157.23 385.08 157.23 381.21 157.17 381.21 157.17 377.32 157.09 377.32 157.09 373.42 156.99 373.42 156.99 369.51 156.89 369.51 156.89 365.58 156.76 365.58 156.76 361.63 156.62 361.63 156.62 357.68 156.47 357.68 156.47 353.72 156.3 353.72 156.3 349.74 156.11 349.74 156.11 345.77 155.9 345.77 155.9 341.78 155.68 341.78 155.68 337.8 155.44 337.8 155.44 333.81 155.19 333.81 155.19 329.82 154.92 329.82 154.92 325.83 154.63 325.83 154.63 321.85 154.32 321.85 154.32 317.86 154 317.86 154 313.89 153.66 313.89 153.66 309.92 153.3 309.92 153.3 305.97 152.93 305.97 152.93 302.02 152.53 302.02 152.53 298.09 152.12 298.09 152.12 294.18 151.69 294.18 151.69 290.28 151.25 290.28 151.25 286.4 150.79 286.4 150.79 282.54 150.31 282.54 150.31 278.7 149.81 278.7 149.81 274.88 149.29 274.88 149.29 271.1 148.76 271.1 148.76 267.34 148.21 267.34 148.21 263.61 147.65 263.61 147.65 259.91 147.07 259.91 147.07 256.24 146.47 256.24 146.47 252.61 145.85 252.61 145.85 249.02 145.22 249.02 145.22 247.23 144.9 247.23 144.9 245.46 144.57 245.46 144.57 243.7 144.24 243.7 144.24 241.95 143.91 241.95 143.91 240.2 143.57 240.2 143.57 238.47 143.23 238.47 143.23 236.75 142.88 236.75 142.88 235.04 142.53 235.04 142.53 233.34 142.18 233.34 142.18 231.66 141.82 231.66 141.82 229.98 141.46 229.98 141.46 228.32 141.1 228.32 141.1 226.67 140.73 226.67 140.73 225.03 140.36 225.03 140.36 223.4 139.99 223.4 139.99 221.79 139.61 221.79 139.61 220.18 139.23 220.18 139.23 218.6 138.84 218.6 138.84 217.02 138.45 217.02 138.45 215.46 138.06 215.46 138.06 213.91 137.66 213.91 137.66 212.38 137.27 212.38 137.27 210.85 136.86 210.85 136.86 209.35 136.46 209.35 136.46 207.85 136.05 207.85 136.05 206.37 135.64 206.37 135.64 204.91 135.23 204.91 135.23 203.46 134.81 203.46 134.81 202.03 134.39 202.03 134.39 200.61 133.97 200.61 133.97 199.2 133.54 199.2 133.54 197.81 133.11 197.81 133.11 196.44 132.68 196.44 132.68 195.08 132.25 195.08 132.25 193.73 131.81 193.73 131.81 192.4 131.37 192.4 131.37 191.09 130.93 191.09 130.93 189.8 130.48 189.8 130.48 188.51 130.04 188.51 130.04 187.25 129.59 187.25 129.59 186 129.14 186 129.14 184.77 128.68 184.77 128.68 183.55 128.23 183.55 128.23 182.36 127.77 182.36 127.77 181.17 127.31 181.17 127.31 180.01 126.85 180.01 126.85 178.86 126.38 178.86 126.38 177.72 125.92 177.72 125.92 176.61 125.45 176.61 125.45 175.51 124.98 175.51 124.98 174.43 124.51 174.43 124.51 173.36 124.03 173.36 124.03 172.32 123.56 172.32 123.56 171.29 123.08 171.29 123.08 170.27 122.6 170.27 122.6 169.28 122.12 169.28 122.12 168.3 121.64 168.3 121.64 167.34 121.16 167.34 121.16 166.39 120.68 166.39 120.68 165.47 120.19 165.47 120.19 164.56 119.71 164.56 119.71 163.67 119.22 163.67 119.22 162.79 118.73 162.79 118.73 161.94 118.24 161.94 118.24 161.1 117.75 161.1 117.75 160.27 117.26 160.27 117.26 159.47 116.77 159.47 116.77 158.68 116.27 158.68 116.27 157.91 115.78 157.91 115.78 157.16 115.28 157.16 115.28 156.43 114.79 156.43 114.79 155.71 114.29 155.71 114.29 155.01 113.8 155.01 113.8 154.33 113.3 154.33 113.3 153.66 112.8 153.66 112.8 153.01 112.31 153.01 112.31 152.38 111.81 152.38 111.81 151.77 111.31 151.77 111.31 151.18 110.81 151.18 110.81 150.6 110.31 150.6 110.31 150.04 109.81 150.04 109.81 149.49 109.32 149.49 109.32 148.96 108.82 148.96 108.82 148.45 108.32 148.45 108.32 147.96 107.82 147.96 107.82 147.48 107.32 147.48 107.32 147.02 106.82 147.02 106.82 146.58 106.33 146.58 106.33 146.15 105.83 146.15 105.83 145.74 105.33 145.74 105.33 145.35 104.83 145.35 104.83 144.97 104.34 144.97 104.34 144.61 103.84 144.61 103.84 144.27 103.35 144.27 103.35 143.94 102.85 143.94 102.85 143.63 102.36 143.63 102.36 143.33 101.86 143.33 101.86 143.05 101.37 143.05 101.37 142.78 100.88 142.78 100.88 142.54 100.39 142.54 100.39 142.3 99.9 142.3 99.9 142.08 99.41 142.08 99.41 141.88 98.92 141.88 98.92 141.69 98.43 141.69 98.43 141.52 97.94 141.52 97.94 141.37 97.46 141.37 97.46 141.22 96.97 141.22 96.97 141.1 96.49 141.1 96.49 140.99 96.01 140.99 96.01 140.89 95.53 140.89 95.53 140.81 95.05 140.81 95.05 140.74 94.57 140.74 94.57 140.68 94.09 140.68 94.09 140.64 93.61 140.64 93.61 140.62 93.14 140.62 93.14 140.6 92.66 140.6 92.66 140.6 92.55 140.6 92.55 140.6 92.49 140.6 92.49 140.6 92.62 140.6 92.62 140.6 93.14 140.6 93.14 140.6 94.19 140.6 94.19 140.6 96.29 140.6 96.29 140.6 104.68 140.6 104.68 140.6 121.47 140.6 121.47 140.6 155.04 140.6 155.04 140.6 222.19"
    stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="9.5"/>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=7.5">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   width="800.000" height="600.000" viewBox="0.0 0.0 800.000 600.000" version="1.1">
<path d="M140.6 222.19l0-129.69c-.05 15.95 26.78 40.96 129.7 56.27c43.75 6.2 86.5 8.5 129.7 8.66c43.2-.16 85.95-2.46 129.7-8.66c102.92-15.31 129.75-40.32 129.7-56.27l0 129.69c.05 15.95-26.78 40.96-129.7 56.27c-43.75 6.2-86.5 8.5-129.7 8.66c-43.2-.16-85.95-2.46-129.7-8.66c-102.92-15.31-129.75-40.32-129.7-56.27"
fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2.5"/>
</svg>
```